# Face Detection using harcascade and Facial Landmark using dlib

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, face-detection

I am using harcascade and facial landmark using dlib methods for face detection using python. But it consumes too much amount of memory and time. Also success ratio is quite less.Is there any other algorithm methods for fast detection?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Cloud Vision. You can detect faces immediately within in no time and Google charges very low price.
Have a look aat this
https://cloud.google.com/vision/